# Unix time returns 0 or some small value in GOLANG

Tags: go

What is wrong with the below GO code? I tried a GO project and deployed in Openshift and everything was fine till yesterday. All of a sudden from today, the time package returns 0

```
val,_ := strconv.ParseInt(string(time.Now().Unix()),10,64)
println("Time now in openshift :",time.Now().Second())
```

So basically actual time here is "1969-12-31". Could be the bug in GO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to convert the time to a string by hand, time.Format does this for you. Or, if you want to print out the seconds since epoch, simply use the [`%d` verb, which is explicitly for printing base10 decimal numbers](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#pkg-overview) <kbd>[Run on playground](http://play.golang.org/p/he9SCTQ5Z-)</kbd>

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello, %s\n",time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339))
    fmt.Printf("Seconds since epoch %d",time.Now().Unix())
}
```

Comment: I dint notice the format function in time package itself.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: The language hint (`<!-- language: lang-go -->`) before the code block wasn't working; it was causing the code not to be highlighted at all.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, why are you using `strconv` if `Unix` already returns an `int64`?

Secondly, `string(int)` conversion [doesn't do what you think it does](http://play.golang.org/p/ERmKxfzXhN). It converts between Unicode code points (aka `rune`s) and strings. You need `strconv.Itoa` here:

```
val, _ := strconv.ParseInt(strconv.FormatInt(time.Now().Unix(), 10), 10, 64)
println("Time now in openshift :", val)
```

http://play.golang.org/p/AC7Q84ZIMC

Comment: you are right. I just started learning :) i changed it to     

val2:=strconv.FormatInt(time.Now().Unix(),10). 

Now everything is fine. Actually i want to get the string from int64

Comment: am wondering how it was working last week without any changes?